# Git: See changes between repository and latest commit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, svn, egit

I use Eclipse with Egit. I want to know how to:

- See all differences between the repository in its current state and the latest commit

I have a Git repository containing some Java projects. I added an empty package to a Java project. The new package had no icon decoration. I wanted it to be marked as untracked, and the project containing the new package to be marked as dirty. Nothing appeared in the commit dialog. When comparing with HEAD and synchronizing with origin/master, no differences showed up.

Comment: These are several unrelated questions rolled into one topic. Please split those up. If you do that you will find out that several of those are already asked and answered here on SO. Did you try to search on the webpage before asking?

Comment: Yes, I did. I searched for hours.

Comment: There were two related questions. I removed one.

Comment: Git does not track folders.

Answer (score 0):

> See all differences between the repository in its current state and the latest commit

```
git diff
```

> When comparing with HEAD and synchronizing with origin/master, no differences showed up.

Git does not track empty folders. Add an empty file into the folder if you want it to be tracked (name it .track or something).